# Что за snippets с "Выполнить код"

Tags: обсуждение, сниппеты

Неоднократно встречаю текст вопрос, в котором есть код, под которым есть кнопка «выполнить код», которая ничего не делает:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что с такими делать? Последний раз, когда я редактировал такое сообщение, я просто удалил этот причудливый текст. Что эта за штука, и не должен ли движок вырезать подобные вещи?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Это встроенный аналог jsFiddle, позволяющий пользователю ввести HTML, JS и CSS исходники и выполнить в песочнице как единое целое. К сожалению, многие новички путаются и не понимают, когда использовать сниппеты, а когда обычное форматирование кода.

В подобных случаях рекомендую просто удалять строки `begin snippet` и `end snippet`.

Справедливо и обратное: если в ответе или вопросе есть ссылка на jsFiddle, полезно перенести код в текст сообщения в виде сниппета.

Comment: Это сниппет вылезает когда надо и когда не надо. Видимо, язык исходника, и необходимость появления, он определяет по движению своих мозговых тараканов. Не считая того, что он реагирует на совершенно нежизнеспособные куски исходников, требующие бОльшего окружения. Очевидно, его AI ещё не дорос до безусловного встраивания куда ни попадя, ergo - должно быть как бета-фича, включаемая юзерами по явному желанию.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что юзеры как раз по явному желанию и жмут, когда не надо, кнопку "Фрагмент кода" вместо "Пример кода". Тут встает вопрос локализации тултипов.

Comment: А.. Только на третий день Зоркий Глаз заметил :) Нафига фообще нужна эта кнопка - "фрагмент кода"? Мало того, что она выглядит как что-то, на что нажимать и в голову не придёт (до тултипа даже не доходит). Так она явно нормальный функционал обеспечить не сможет.

Comment: почему не может? она создает jsFiddle-подобную песочницу.

Comment: P.S. Вот тут подсказывают, что вид кнопки привычней пхп-хтмл-щикам, а не фигурные скобки. Ну так и оставить одну из них.

Comment: "*подобную*" именно что подобную. как оторванный от окружения фрагмент кода может быть исполнен? если это не банальный `alert("ляляля")`

Comment: фиддл/сниппет это и есть минимальный кусок html+js+css, который может быть исполнен. В редакторе есть панелька, позволяющая подключить JQuery, d3, Knockout, Angular или любую другую либу по урлу.

Comment: да вместо "фрагмент кода", лучше "живой javascript код" использовать (передать смысл, что на клиенте будет выполняться -- потому что так можно (в принципе) и [Питон исполнять](http://www.skulpt.org/).

Comment: Как уже было сказано, важен в том числе и текст подсказки. Сам помню, что в первый раз не разобрался и нажал на "Фрагмент кода", но разобравшись, понял, что это мне не требуется. Думаю, у многих новичков есть с этим проблема.